# How to record Adobe Photoshop Photomerge action?

Tags: photoshop, adobe

I'm trying to record a Photomerge action in Adobe Photoshop, so that I can re-use this action for batch photo merging. However I'm only able to record the first step of the Photomerge, i.e: Layout and Source File select window.

How can I also record subsequent actions for the Photomerge function? Such as layout select or photo sources?

Thank You!

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/157012/how-to-record-adobe-photoshop-photomerge-action

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't.
Photomerge is PS plugin which start external executable where PS have no control and can't capture any action done there. With this software the role of PS is to "provide" the source image(s) and after the end to "grab" the output.

Comment: Is there anyway I can use Photomerge in Photoshop to batch stitch panorama photos or maybe automate it a bit? Rather than manually selecting images each time.

Comment: @user2028856, check about this in Photomerge, automation, presets, something like